# How to call methods that use custom implementation trait?

Tags: rust

Consider this example:

```rs
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
trait Map<K, V> {
    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V>;
}
impl<K: ToString, V> Map<K, V> for BTreeMap<K, V> {
    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V> {
        println!("{}", key.to_string());
        Some(value)
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    let output = map.insert("key", "value");
    // expected output: `Some("value")`
    println!("{:?}", output); // But Got: `None`
}
```

As you can see I am trying to call a method in `Map<K, V>` trait, that has a method called `insert(..)`,

Why rust didn't  called that method (`insert`) from `Map<K, V>` trait, Why It didn't work?

But, If I rename this method in different name, let say `set(..)`, It worked!

Comment: By "overriding", here, you really mean you want to replace the existing `insert` method of `BTreeMap` ? In OOP overriding is done on a subclass, not on the same struct

Comment: No! Even its impossible replace any method in rust, All I need was to call my version of implementation...

Comment: Then I suggest you change your question to remove the "override" word as you want to call your own function which just happens to have the same name. Your problem seems to be about [disambiguating](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/disambiguating.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [***fully qualified call***](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) in order to disambiguating the call to your implementation:

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
trait Map<K, V> {
    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V>;
}
impl<K: ToString, V> Map<K, V> for BTreeMap<K, V> {
    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V> {
        println!("{}", key.to_string());
        Some(value)
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    let output = Map::insert(&mut map, "key", "value");
    // expected output: `Some("value")`
    println!("{:?}", output); // But Got: `None`
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=051a8174ded86db8ec3584c1b6411ede)

Comment: Can't rust  call this function automatically ? Lets say All I need is, To just import that specific implementation... like: `use Map`

Comment: @Nur, it is not possible, because the compiler do not know how to resolve that.

Comment: More details in the [rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 1):

The question of "how?" was already answered, but I'll try to add a little of "why is it so?"

---

It's impossible to do in the way you think, because compiler prefers inherent method over trait implementations.

The reasons might be multiple, but one of them is simple: backwards compatibility. If trait methods were to take precedence over inherent ones, the downstream code could suddenly break - or, even worse, silently change behavior! - when someone upstream implements a trait with colliding methods. Consider the following code, for example:

```
// Let's imagine that this is an external crate.
mod with_trait {
    pub trait Map<K, V> {
        fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V>;
    }
    impl<K, V> Map<K, V> for std::collections::HashMap<K, V> {
        fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V> {
            Some(value)
        }
    }
    // impl<K, V> Map<K, V> for std::collections::BTreeMap<K, V> {
    //     fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V> {
    //         Some(value)
    //     }
    // }
}

// ...and this is your own code.
fn main() {
    use std::collections::{BTreeMap, HashMap};
    use with_trait::Map;

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    // Maybe you're currently using an implementation for HashMap;
    // here we use a fully-qualified syntax, so that the assertion passes
    assert!(Map::insert(&mut map, "key", "value").is_some());

    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    // ...but if trait methods were to take precedence, then
    // by uncommenting `impl Map for BTreeMap`
    // this assertion would be broken!
    assert!(map.insert("key", "value").is_none());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de15cae57b443f43664a24ada82294f1)

In practice, it's considered [minor change to implement a non-fundamental trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1105-api-evolution.md#minor-change-implementing-any-non-fundamental-trait), so this potential hazard was reviewed and mitigated.